# Throws himself down on

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice, sentence-choice

Context: Derek is standing on the top of a scaffold when a man starts shooting at him. Derek doesn't get hit.

1. Derek **throws himself down on the scaffold** as the man keeps shooting.
2. Derek **throws himself flat on the scaffold** as the man keeps shooting.
3. Derek **throws himself down flat on the scaffold** as the man keeps shooting.
4. Derek **drops down on the scaffold** as the man keeps shooting.
5. Derek **drops flat on the scaffold** as the man keeps shooting.
6. Derek **drops down flat on the scaffold** as the man keeps shooting.

Could you please tell me if any of my suggestions are natural in the context?

Comment: They all could work. "Throws himself" sounds a little more panicked than "drops".

Comment: Could I just write 'throws himself down" and omit "on the scaffold" or could it sound like he threw himself down from the scaffold?

Comment: It could sound like that, since a scaffold is usually elevated.

Comment: To me #4 sounds most natural, but I would suggest “onto” instead of “on”.

Answer (score 0):

For me "throws *something* down" against "drops *something*"
conveys a more (physically) active involvement
than just the passive action of gravity.